# Reading multiple records

Tags: c#, csv, record

I am sort of a beginner and this is my first task with c#.

I want to write a code that reads through records, if the record matches the search term, it will print the record on the screen. However, I want it to go through all the records and then print all that have a matching search term. At the moment it only prints the first matching records, I want it to print ALL records that have a matching search term. How do I modify the code to do that? I think it only requires a simple modification but I can't seem to figure it out.

[This is my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n69qo.png)

Comment: Post that code in the text format!

Comment: Please check out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question so we can help you as best as we can.

Comment: Reading CSV files line-by-line is doomed to fail when one of the fields contains multiple lines of text. Try to use a CSV-capable library unless you feel like implementing [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Answer (score 0):

If you want go through all records you should loop through all fields, in your method RecordMatches, because you pass array to that method, use for or foreach loop and inside loop check for match, and on every match print fields (record) value.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@filePath);
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string[] fields = lines[i].Split(',');
    RecordMatches(searchTerm, fields);
}


public static void RecordMatches(string searchTerm, string records[])
{
    foreach(string record in records)
    {
        if(record.Trim().Equals(searchTerm.Trim()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the

```
return fields;
```

when the record matches. `return` exits the function and prevents it finding more than one match.